# PyQt QTableWidget horizontalheaderlabel stylesheet

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, stylesheet

I used this to set the style for my `QTableWidget`. Everything in the table is affected except the `horizontalheaderlabels` and `the row numbers`.

```
Table.setStyleSheet("Background-color:rgb(100,100,100);border-radius:15px;")
```

So I tried this

```
Table.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet("Background-color:rgb(190,1,1);border-radius:14px;"
```

But this doesn't seems to have any affect.

How do i set the style sheet for `horizontalheaderlabel` and `the row numbers`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should check [Qt Sylesheet Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qheaderview)

You have to do something like

```
stylesheet = "::section{Background-color:rgb(190,1,1);border-radius:14px;}"
Table.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
```

That is if you want different horizontal and vertical headers. Otherwise, this should do the job

```
stylesheet = "QHeaderView::section{Background-color:rgb(190,1,1);
                                   border-radius:14px;}"
Table.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
```

Comment: what does `::section` thing do? normally i would just write `("Background-color:rgb(255,255,0);")`

Comment: If you apply a stylesheet directly on a horizontal header, it will apply on the header "background", i.e. not on the text cells of your header. That's what ::section is for. Alternatively, you could've used QHeaderview::section{...} and apply the stylesheet directly on your table widget

Answer (score 0):

```
style_sheet = """
QTableView {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    gridline-color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
}

QTableView::item:selected {
    background-color: #87CEFA;
    color: black;
}

QHeaderView::section {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 2px;
}

QHeaderView::section:horizontal {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

QHeaderView::section:vertical {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

QTableView::indicator {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

QTableView::indicator:checked {
    background-color: #87CEFA;
}

QTableView::indicator:unchecked {
    background-color: white;
}
"""
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).