# Color individual horizontal headers of QTableWidget in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a QTableWidget where I would like to color individual horizontal header items based on some criterion.

What I have come up with so far:

```
stylesheet = "::section{Background-color:rgb(190,1,1)}"
self.ui.Table.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
```

This works, however it colors all headers simultaneously without me being able to change the color of an individual header. So the next logical step would be:

```
self.ui.Table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
```

This does not work, as a single header item does not support setting a stylesheet.

Finally:

```
self.ui.Table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setBackgroundColor(QtCore.Qt.red)
```

This runs just fine without python complaining, however it does not seem to have any effect on the background color whatsoever.

I already looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198634/pyqt-qtablewidget-horizontalheaderlabel-stylesheet), it is what sparked my first attempt. However it only deals with coloring all headers with the same color.

**How can I color the headers individually?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using the following recipe:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyFrame(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None,initials=None):
        QtWidgets.QFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(5,3,self)
        self.table.move(30,30)
        self.table.resize(400,300)

        item1 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('red')
        item1.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0,item1)

        item2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('green')
        item2.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0))
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1,item2)

        item3 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('blue')
        item3.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255))
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2,item3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('Fusion')) # won't work on windows style.
    Frame = MyFrame(None)
    Frame.resize(500,400)
    Frame.show()
    app.exec_()
```

, that will result in this:

[image: Different colors for header items in QTableWidget]

One thing you must consider is that Windows style does not let you do this. This is the reason why I had to change the style to Fusion.

Comment: Unfortunately I am forced to use PyQt4. After I adjusted all the imports, I get a table with uncoloured headers. I guess this feature just does not seem to work with PyQt4. I will wait some time if anyone comes up with a solution for PyQt4. Otherwise I will mark yours as the accepted answer for any PyQt5 users struggling with this.

Comment: Are you sure? Excluding imports everything (regarding this example) should be working the same way. Did you change the app style? "app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))" Try with other styles, since I don't know if the permissions changed between Qt versions. For "Windows" style I'm reasonably sure it won't work, no matter the Qt version.

Comment: you are right, it does work with plastique and cleanlooks, not with fusion or windows however

Comment: Hi, is it possible to change the counter column on the left only? (1, 2, 3, 4...)

Answer (score 2):

> ***setBackground seems to have no effect When used in header***

See this:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/74609/cannot-set-the-backgroud-color-of-the-horizontalheaderitem-of-qtablewidget/2

I wrote this small app; font type and size and foreground color take effect.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QFont

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

columns = ['Column 0', 'Column 1', 'Column 2']
items = [['Row%s Col%s' % (row, col) for col in range(len(columns))] for row in range(1)]

view = QtGui.QTableWidget()

view.setColumnCount(len(columns))
view.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(columns)
view.setRowCount(len(items))
for row, item in enumerate(items):
    for col, column_name in enumerate(item):
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("%s" % column_name)
        view.setItem(row, col, item)
    view.setRowHeight(row, 16)

fnt = QFont()
fnt.setPointSize(15)
fnt.setBold(True)
fnt.setFamily("Arial")

item1 = view.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
item1.setForeground(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
item1.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))  # Black background! does not work!!
item1.setFont(fnt)

item2 = view.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
item2.setForeground(QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0))
item2.setFont(fnt)

item3 = view.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
item3.setForeground(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 255))

view.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item1)
view.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item2)
view.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item3)
view.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: Add `app.setStyle (QStyleFactory.create ('Fusion'))` after `app = QApplication ([])` and `setBackground` will start working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modification of [armatita's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196988/color-individual-horizontal-headers-of-qtablewidget-in-pyqt/36197865#36197865) working with the default Windows style:

```py
import sys
from PySide6 import QtGui, QtWidgets


class ColoredTableHeaderStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def drawControl(self, element, option, painter, widget=None):
        if element == QtWidgets.QStyle.ControlElement.CE_HeaderSection and isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QHeaderView):
            fill = option.palette.brush(QtGui.QPalette.ColorRole.Window)  # the Qt implementation actually sets the background brush on the Window color role, the default Windows style simply ignores it
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, fill)  # fill the header section with the background brush
        else:
            self.baseStyle().drawControl(element, option, painter, widget)  # use the default implementation in all other cases


class MyFrame(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(5, 3, self)
        self.table.move(30, 30)
        self.table.resize(400, 300)

        item1 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('red')
        item1.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item1)

        item2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('green')
        item2.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0))
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item2)

        item3 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('blue')
        item3.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255))
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(ColoredTableHeaderStyle(app.style()))  # use the proxy style reimplementing the drawing of table headers, otherwise identical with the default Windows style
    Frame = MyFrame(None)
    Frame.resize(500, 400)
    Frame.show()
    app.exec_()
```

It can be refined by using a custom subclass of `QHeaderView` to modify only the horizontal header to be colored. It also works for a `QTableView`.